# Can I have both "disallow nothing" and "disallow something" statements in my robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt, disallow

I had to make an update to an update to a robots.txt to disallow access to sub directory. There was already a disallow statement but i added another one, is the updated robots.txt file below correct ?

**The previous robots.txt :**

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

**The updated robots.txt (note the addition of the 3rd line) :**

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Disallow: /terms/*
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, but the second statement renders the first obsolete. Essentially, in human-readable terms, you're saying:

*All bots

Disallow nothing - so crawl anything you want

But Disallow the "terms" directory - don't crawl that

Sitemap here*

Above, you can take out the second line, to tell the bots to not crawl the "terms" directory.

Thus, this would work:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /terms/
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: I know that Googlebot uses the "longest line that matches" as a rule for which line takes precedence.   However, I suspect that some bots would get confused.

Comment: You don't need a blank disallow like: "Disallow: " - So I agree with this comment

Comment: The `*` in `/terms/*` should be removed. It’s superfluous for consumers like Google, and harmful for consumers that follow the original robots.txt spec (where `*` has no special meaning).

Comment: @unor Great catch. While I wouldn't be too concerned with the original spec - as specs are meant to evolve, for example the Allow directive was not in the original spec - I agree that the wildcard is superfluous. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out!